# How do C# byte arrays represent very large numbers in cryptographic operations?

Tags: c#

I have a mathematical understanding of how cryptographic algorithms like RSA and Diffie-Hellman work, and I have been with .NET for some time. But it always bothers me how C# uses byte arrays to represent keys and key materials. I know these are supposed to be very large numbers in most cases. Therefore, it makes sense how difficult it would be to store and do arithmetic them as other primitive data types. But how does C# represent them as arrays of 8-bit unsigned integers and manipulate them?

Comment: I don't believe they are interpreted as arrays of 8-bit integers, but rather as a sufficient number of bits to represent the desired number stored contiguously in memory, which in C# is represented by an array. I haven't looked at the runtime's cryptographic implementation, but I imagine BigInteger might be used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0

Comment: It is the same way as you learned math in elementary school. In base 10 you have place holders 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1.  And you did the math based on the columns.  With an array of bytes your columns are 16777216, 65836, 256, 1.  Math is done the same that you would do in elementary school except in base 256.

Comment: It is a "blob" in crypto-speak.  While such numbers could be represented with BigInteger, C# does not do actually do anything with the number.  It hands the job to a trusted well-researched algorithm written in a native language that's been around for a very long time.  Which has no use for BigInteger, its wants a blob.  [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptimportkey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# or not, from machine's perspective there are only bytes (or even bits). Everything is a number. So say we have a byte array, for example `1 2 3`. It turns out it is a number, in decimal format equal to

```
3*1 + 2*256 + 1*256*256 == 66051
```

depending on how exactly you interpret the order (see: [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). This is base 256 representation. 256 because one byte is 8 bits, and so it represents numbers between 0 and 255.

So, this process can be reversed. If you have a number, say `66051` (what a surprise), then you can reverse the above (by doing division with remainders) to obtain `1 2 3` byte array.

In other words byte array is simply a way to represent a number. And in fact more can be done with such byte arrays. We can add them and multiply them, just like you add and multiply base 10 numbers, just like kids in school do this, by adding/multiplying piece by piece, carrying over numbers, and so on.

Of course modern machines/algorithms optimize this process (for example by treating a sequence of 8 bytes as a single 64-bit integer, by applying special SIMD instructions, etc), but the core idea remains the same as addition and multiplication in elementary school.

**The point is: byte arrays and numbers are pretty much the same thing.**

In fact, I wrote `66051` earlier, which is a byte array as well! Except it is base 10, the standard representation we humans use nowadays. But machines work better with powers of 2. In practice you need to represent an abstract number is some way, and so machines just use a slightly different one.

> Therefore, it makes sense how difficult it would be to store and do arithmetic them as other primitive data types.

You may think that since crypto algorithms deal with big numbers it is difficult. But in practice the size of data they work on is around few thousands of bytes. It is like nothing for modern machine.

Doing a single arithmetic operation on such sizes is also nothing. Of course those algorithms are designed in such a way that they require lots of arithmetic operations to process the data, reverse engineering is especially hard. But this is an intrinsic property of algorithm itself, not really because it deals with few thousands of bytes.

For example nowadays RSA is considered obsolete (even though it still is widely used), and elliptic-curve algorithms are preferred. Which are not only faster and believed to be more secure, but also more compact - the data they deal with is around 10x smaller. Yet the difficulty of reverse engineering is even higher.